# Unknown argument: -release

Tags: java, android, ant

I am facing an issue with **Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536)**, so I found [this post](https://github.com/mmin18/Dex65536) that can help me resolve this error. But as you will see in that post that it needed ant installation. So I started learning the docs for ANT and completed installation of ANT.

But now I cannot fire ***ant -release*** command, although I was able to fire ***ant -debug***. The complete log of ***ant -help*** and ***ant -version*** has been attached to this if it could help anyone. You can see in here that is doesn't have ***ant -release*** command:

```
D:\xxxxxandroid\NilayNew\xxxxxx>ant -help
ant [options] [target [target2 [target3] ...]]
Options:
  -help, -h              print this message
  -projecthelp, -p       print project help information
  -version               print the version information and exit
  -diagnostics           print information that might be helpful to
                         diagnose or report problems.
  -quiet, -q             be extra quiet
  -silent, -S            print nothing but task outputs and build failures
  -verbose, -v           be extra verbose
  -debug, -d             print debugging information
  -emacs, -e             produce logging information without adornments
  -lib <path>            specifies a path to search for jars and classes
  -logfile <file>        use given file for log
    -l     <file>                ''
  -logger <classname>    the class which is to perform logging
  -listener <classname>  add an instance of class as a project listener
  -noinput               do not allow interactive input
  -buildfile <file>      use given buildfile
    -file    <file>              ''
    -f       <file>              ''
  -D<property>=<value>   use value for given property
  -keep-going, -k        execute all targets that do not depend
                         on failed target(s)
  -propertyfile <name>   load all properties from file with -D
                         properties taking precedence
  -inputhandler <class>  the class which will handle input requests
  -find <file>           (s)earch for buildfile towards the root of
    -s  <file>           the filesystem and use it
  -nice  number          A niceness value for the main thread:
       1 (lowest) to 10 (highest); 5 is the default
  -nouserlib             Run ant without using the jar files from
          ${user.home}/.ant/lib
  -noclasspath           Run ant without using CLASSPATH
  -autoproxy             Java1.5+: use the OS proxy settings
  -main <class>          override Ant's normal entry point

D:\xxxxxandroid\NilayNew\xxxxxx>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
```

Can anyone suggest me what went wrong or what is it that I am missing ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

***ant -debug***, ***ant -help*** and ***ant -version*** are out-of-the-box funcionality of ANT.

Please read ANT documentation from: http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html

ANT by defalut use build.xml file that contain configuration (what 'methods'/procedures are invoked). ANT is looking for '-release' target in that file and if doesn't exist, it crash...

1. Check build.xml looking for '-release' target
2. Recheck what command you need to execute

Why you want to launch ***ant -release***?